# Is it valid VCF not to 'squash' positions with more than one ALT allele?

Tags: vcf, file-formats, pbwt

I'm seeing output from [PBWT](https://github.com/VertebrateResequencing/pbwt) that looks like this:

```
3   112841  rs78923776  C   G   .   PASS    RefPanelAF=0.000153988;AN=2;AC=0;INFO=1 GT:ADS:DS:GP    0|0:0,0:0:1,0,0
3   112841  rs78923776  C   T   .   PASS    RefPanelAF=0.078534;AN=2;AC=1;INFO=1    GT:ADS:DS:GP    0|1:0,1:1:0,1,0
```

The first line says that my genome is `CC` at this position, but the second line (for the second alt allele) says that my genome is `CT` at this position. OK, the first line couldn't say this, so it calls me as REF/REF, but this call has to be interpreted in the context of the second call, and can't be taken at face value.

That's why I wonder if this is valid VCF or if it's actually breaking the specification.

The line should be 'squashed' down to the following (I think):

```
3   112841  rs78923776  C   G,T .   PASS    RefPanelAF=0.000153988,0.078534;AN=3;AC=0,1;INFO=1  GT:ADS:DS:GP    0|2:0,0:0:1,0,0
```

Comment: Many pieces of software can only work with biallelic diploid calls, so they have to split up multiallelic genotypes into separate lines.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a standard way to work out the genotype call?

Answer (score 2):

It is a valid multi-allelic entry, and most variant callers produce such entries. However, comparison between two such gets more complicated. With biallelic entries, 2 CHR-POS-REF-ALT entries either match or they don't. With multi-allelic entries, they can match completely, partially or not at all, which means you also need to be able to specify how much of a match is a partial match etc. This is a hindrance in annotation processes that annotate using the CHR-POS-REF-ALT fields.

This also introduces cases where an indel can become a multi-allelic entry with a nearby SNV like so:

```
chr1    100    GA    G
chr1    101    A    AA
```

can now be represented as

```
chr1    100    GA    G,AA
```

which can get confusing. Operations are always *more predictable* when VCF has been decomposed and left-aligned.

Comment: Good to know this is valid. I'm having trouble interpreting some of the genotypes I'm seeing. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the difficulty you're facing?

Comment: Hi @Ram, there are several genotype call combinations that I don't know how to 'decode'. I've written up a report here:
https://github.com/richarddurbin/pbwt/issues/52#issuecomment-1064125959

The simplest way I can describe it is to say that, if the call is split across two lines (for a tri-allelic variant) the REF part of the call should be the same on both lines, no?

Comment: I glanced through your thread there and I think you're in the gray area between biology and bioinformatics. VCF entries assume reference sequence is reality, so yes, a multi-allelic site, when split, will have the same REF bases. Assuming that the mutated site is still diploid, a tri-allelic variant will have GT `1/2` where 1 is ALT-1 and 2-ALT-2 (so no REF base)

Comment: Right, I'd put that in VCF as something like `./1` and `./1` (assuming I had to split alternative alleles out into separate bi-allelic lines for some reason).

Comment: Yes, that's what decomposers do - they give you `1/.` GT entries.